# Where can I find geological maps for countries from Africa?

Tags: geology, mapping, mining, resources

I am interested in geological maps for multiple African countries: Egypt, Sudan, and Ivory Coast. Is there any geoportal available for Africa, something similar to [geokniga](https://www.geokniga.org/) or [vsegei](http://webmapget.vsegei.ru/index.html), but for Arican countries? Or other free resources from where I could source these maps? 
I did find a paid resource, [East View Geospatial](https://shop.geospatial.com/), but I would very much prefer a free option if one exists. 
For Egypt and for Sudan(partially) I found some free resources, but I decided to ask here as well, maybe the community here knows some other portals.

Comment: Hi, what do you need the maps for? Do you want to print them or use them in a computer program?

Comment: I am interested in using them in a computer program, for some GIS analysis and maybe playing a bit with Blender and creating some nice 3D models.

Answer (score 4):

You may find some of the maps you seek on the [OneGeology](https://www.onegeology.org/portal/home.html) portal, which gives access to both regional mapping and maps uploaded by national geological surveys. You could also review the data available on the [African Groundwater Atlas](https://www.bgs.ac.uk/geology-projects/africa-groundwater-atlas/) page, which has maps and links to hydrogeological (and geological) resources, although the amount of data may vary by country, depending on how much data has been placed in the public domain.